# Insert Into XML Data into SQL Server Table

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql

I am trying to import data from an XML file into a table in SQL Server. Below is an example of the XML file

```
<Publication>
    <Addressee SubscriberReference='PCI1' CompanyName='TestCompany1' CompanyNumber=''>
        <Address PostalAddressRef='1' FlatNumber='' BuildingName='' StreetNumber='' PostCode='xx1 xxx' AddressLine1='' AddressLine2='' AddressLine3='' AddressLine4='' AddressLine5='' CountryCode='GB' POBoxNumber='' CountryCodeDesc='United Kingdom' UKStandardAddressInd='false' AddressLocationTypeId='B' AddressLocationTypeDesc='British' SystemEventRef='' SubEventRef='1' EndingSubEventRef='' SystemEventId='0' SystemEvent='Unknown'/>
    </Addressee>
</Publication>
```

This is the code i have written. It creates the row in the table however its a blank record

```
INSERT INTO XMLCommTest (CompanyName)
SELECT
   MY_XML.Pub.query('CompanyName').value('(Publication/Addressee/@CompanyName)[1]', 'VARCHAR(250)')
FROM (SELECT CAST(MY_XML AS xml)
      FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\cfs\XMLCommTest\LBA0_Comm_Stmts_305741_202301310000.txt', SINGLE_BLOB) AS T(MY_XML)) AS T(MY_XML)
      CROSS APPLY MY_XML.nodes('Publication/Addressee') AS MY_XML (Pub) ;
```

Can anyone let me know what i have done wrong in the code because the field is definitely there so not sure why i am getting blank filed returned

Comment: You need to bulk import the file.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/examples-of-bulk-import-and-export-of-xml-documents-sql-server?force_isolation=true&view=sql-server-ver16#sample-data-file

Comment: @jdweng They are bulk importing it, what should they do different regarding `OPENROWSET(BULK`

Comment: @Charlieface : The code posted is not reading the file.  The link shows how to read the file.  The answer below does not read the file.

Comment: @jdweng The code above says `FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\cfs\XMLCommTest\LBA0_Comm_Stmts_305741_202301310000.txt', SINGLE_BLOB)` not sure what you mean

Comment: When i change the MY_XML.pub.query line to "MY_XML.Pub.value('@CompanyName','varchar(250)')" in worked fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're using `.query` to the node `CompanyName` *and* then looking for the nodes `Publication/Addressee` when you've already navigated to them. You're effectively looking for `Publication/Addressee/CompanyName/Publication/Addressee` and then trying to return the property `CompanyName`.

You just need to use `value`. This uses a variable, rather than `OPENROWSET` but shows the correct solution:

```sql
DECLARE @XML xml = '<Publication>
    <Addressee SubscriberReference=''PCI1'' CompanyName=''TestCompany1'' CompanyNumber=''''>
        <Address PostalAddressRef=''1'' FlatNumber='''' BuildingName='''' StreetNumber='''' PostCode=''xx1 xxx'' AddressLine1='''' AddressLine2='''' AddressLine3='''' AddressLine4='''' AddressLine5='''' CountryCode=''GB'' POBoxNumber='''' CountryCodeDesc=''United Kingdom'' UKStandardAddressInd=''false'' AddressLocationTypeId=''B'' AddressLocationTypeDesc=''British'' SystemEventRef='''' SubEventRef=''1'' EndingSubEventRef='''' SystemEventId=''0'' SystemEvent=''Unknown''/>
    </Addressee>
</Publication>';


SELECT MY_XML.Pub.value('@CompanyName','varchar(250)')
FROM @XML.nodes('Publication/Addressee') MY_XML(Pub);
```

Comment: Thank you, i thought i had done something wrong. All working now 